# Octave profiler, what does the 'self' time accounts for?

Tags: time, octave, profiler, execution

I have a question regarding the information the octave profiler outputs.

I have the following piece of code :

```
% script to illustrate the octave profiler

%% clean the environment
close all;
clear all;
clc;

%% draw gaussian multivariate random samples

% set the dimension of the r.v.
n       = 5000;

% set the parameters of the distribution
meanV       = ones(n, 1);
covM        = eye(n);

% set the number of samples to draw
nSamples    = 1000;

% start the profiler
profile on;

[smpls]     = getMvnSmpls(meanV, covM, nSamples);

% stop the profiler
profile off
% obtain the profiler data
profData    = profile("info");
% display the profiler info
profshow(profData, 20);
```

where the function 'getMvnSmpls' is the following

```
function [smpls] = getMvnSmpls(meanV, covM, nSamples)

    % determine the size of the r.v.
    n   = length(meanV);

    % allocate the memory to store the output samples
    smpls   = zeros(nSamples, n);

    % draw the samples
    for k=1:nSamples
        if mod(k, 50) == 0
            fprintf('iteration %d/%d \n', k, nSamples);
        smpls(k, :) = mvnrnd(meanV, covM);
    end

end
```

The output I get from the octave profiler is:

```
   #    Function Attr     Time (s)        Calls
-----------------------------------------------
  26        chol            59.162           20
   9        norm             4.448           20
  10    binary *             0.678           60
   1 getMvnSmpls             0.294            1
   3       zeros             0.037            1
  11      mvnrnd             0.010           20
  27       randn             0.004           20
   6     fprintf             0.002           20
  23     warning             0.002           40
   4         mod             0.001         1000
  12    issquare             0.001           20
  25    binary +             0.001           40
   5   binary ==             0.001         1080
  20    isscalar             0.000           20
  24         eye             0.000           20
  16        size             0.000          100
  14   binary !=             0.000           81
   8         eps             0.000           20
  13      nargin             0.000           61
  22         any             0.000           20
```

I ran the profexplore command as well and the result is the following:

```
profexplore(profData)

Top
  1) getMvnSmpls: 1 calls, 64.643 total, 0.294 self
  2) profile: 1 calls, 0.000 total, 0.000 self

profexplore> 1

Top
  getMvnSmpls: 1 calls, 64.643 total, 0.294 self
    1) mvnrnd: 20 calls, 59.860 total, 0.010 self
    2) norm: 20 calls, 4.448 total, 4.448 self
    3) zeros: 1 calls, 0.037 total, 0.037 self
    4) fprintf: 20 calls, 0.002 total, 0.002 self
    5) mod: 1000 calls, 0.001 total, 0.001 self
    6) binary ==: 1000 calls, 0.001 total, 0.001 self
    7) eps: 20 calls, 0.000 total, 0.000 self
    8) binary *: 20 calls, 0.000 total, 0.000 self
    9) length: 1 calls, 0.000 total, 0.000 self
    10) prefix -: 1 calls, 0.000 total, 0.000 self
```

My question is what does the 'self' time represents for the function 'getMvnSmpls'? What operations are accounted for in that time?

As I look at the expression of the function I see that all the function calls, i.e. length, zeros, mod, fprintf, mvnrnd, have their own dedicated time, so I am not sure what is accounted as the execution time of the function itself.

The example that I presented is a contrived one to keep things simple. The code that I profile is very similar to the example that I gave. What intrigued me was the fact that for a function very similar to 'getMvnSmpls' (it contains a for loop, several variable initialisation and the pre-computation of some constant quantities that arise in the for loop, which have their own computation time) the execution time (self) was close to 6 seconds. It is true that the function is called three times. However, I find that close to 2 seconds execution time for the function itself is a bit much. I would like, if possible, to cut down from the execution time, but as I don't know what constitutes the execution time of the function itself I don't know where to begin from.

Many thanks,
Andrei

Comment: This post may be useful: http://octave.1599824.n4.nabble.com/profiler-can-someone-explain-self-td4671603.html

Comment: "self" time is time that routine was executing without calling any other routine, or at least not calling any other routine that the profiler knows about. "Inclusive" time is more revealing because a routine can be wasteful simply by calling other routines too much. Besides, it includes "self" time. Of course, the whole thing is not showing you I/O time. If the program's slowness is due to reading/writing files, or shelling other apps, it won't show you that.